Error when trying to get answer using qa_chain
I'm following this tutorial and I'm at the step where I am testing chatting with the AI chatbot. I have created the qa_chain and I am using it similar to how it is in the tutorial but I am getting the following error after I input my question and it tries generating the answer:
generated_sequence = self.model.generate(

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

TypeError: transformers.generation.utils.GenerationMixin.generate() got multiple values for keyword argument 'pad_token_id'

I am wondering what this issue could be coming from? I checked the collab provided in the tutorial and I can't seem to find any significant differences between my code and theirs.
Thanks

The error should come from instruct_pipeline = pipeline(model=model_name, torch_dtype=torch.bfloat16, trust_remote_code=True, device_map="auto",                                return_full_text=True, max_new_tokens=256, top_p=0.95, top_k=50, model_kwargs={'load_in_8bit': True})
